# Neo4j - Does the index exist or not?

Tags: neo4j

I'm having a frustrating problem; I have a database containing nodes with a label 'ABC'. I tried these two cypher queries:

```
MATCH (n:ABC)
USING INDEX n:ABC(ENTITY)
WHERE n.ENTITY = 'John Lennon'
RETURN n;
```

This one works fine. The second one, however, does not.

```
START n = node:ABC(ENTITY='John Lennon') RETURN n;
```

Where I get an error, Neo.ClientError.Schema.NoSuchIndex. I don't understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing legacy indexes (2) and schema indexes (1).

Stick with [schema indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/graphdb-neo4j-schema.html) (1) - you don't even have to specify them.

Ignore [legacy indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing.html) if you don't have to do fulltext-search.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. I am however using a UniqueNodeFactory for another node property, that property will use legacy indexes I assume?